# Building an Angular app that won't run in the root of public_html

Tags: angular, angular8

I implemented a conventional angular app. The problem is it won't run in the root of the domain, but in a subfolder. When I generate the app, the index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>Backend</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.fc351d6e19ae3ad0f023.css"></head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
<script src="runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.7784ace277a2ec6cc920.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.741402d1d47331ce975c.js" nomodule></script><script src="polyfills-es5.ae350e3469dc8aba722c.js" nomodule></script><script src="scripts.73905d6ee8dce4ede414.js"></script><script src="main-es2015.e77f6ad52f12c15144d3.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.a7f7a3ca564e8841fd71.js" nomodule></script></body>
</html>
```

And the problem is the scripts and styles aren't loading, since these are being searched at the root. I tried changing the base node, but it doesn't't work. So each time I build, I have to edit the index.html file with the full path to these files. Like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demo.com/backend/" />
    <title>Backend</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.com/backend/styles.fc351d6e19ae3ad0f023.css"></head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
<script src="https://demo.com/backend/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" type="module"></script><script src="https://demo.com/backend/polyfills-es2015.7784ace277a2ec6cc920.js" type="module"></script><script src="https://demo.com/backend/runtime-es5.741402d1d47331ce975c.js" nomodule></script><script src="https://demo.com/backend/polyfills-es5.ae350e3469dc8aba722c.js" nomodule></script><script src="https://demo.com/backend/scripts.73905d6ee8dce4ede414.js"></script><script src="https://demo.com/backend/main-es2015.e77f6ad52f12c15144d3.js" type="module"></script><script src="https://demo.com/backend/main-es5.a7f7a3ca564e8841fd71.js" nomodule></script></body>
</html>
```

Any idea about how make such changes automatically or in an elegant way?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use your web server to remap the requested url to any physical folder / file you want. First place your angular app in a folder not served by your web server. Then, using ASP.NET Core you can craft a controller like this:

```
[Route("[controller]/{*catchall}")]
public IActionResult CatchAll(string catchall)
{
    // convert url to physical file path
    string file = Path.Combine(folderForAngularApp, catchall);

    // retrive the physical file and return it using the correct type
    string suffix = Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower();
    switch (suffix)
    {
      case ".js": return PhysicalFile(file, "text/javascript");
      case ".html": return PhysicalFile(file, "text/html");
      case ".css": return PhysicalFile(file, "text/css");
      default: return NotFound();
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can also control access to your SPA, ie allowing only authenticated users to download it.

Comment: I don't have access to the server. I just can upload files to a subfolder, but can't change anything on its config. Any idea?

Comment: in this case I would:
1) Create a script to change index.html. With Powershell you can do something like 

(Get-Content "index.html").Replace("runtime-es2015","/demo.com/backend/runtime-es2015") | Set-Content "index.html"

2) Use your IDE to invoke the script automatically after compilation. In Visual Studio it's in project properties / compilation events.